# Django 1.8 AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'push'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Here is the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/addinterest/

Django Version: 1.8.2
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'myapp')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     `response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)`
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 `return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)`
File "/~/myapp/views.py" in add_interest
  155.     `return render_to_response('add_interests.html', context, {'form': form})`
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render_to_response
  45.             `using=using)`
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  116.                         `template_name, context, context_instance, dirs, dictionary)`
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py" in render_to_string
  220.         `with context_instance.push(context):`

Exception Type: AttributeError at /myapp/addinterest/
Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute 'push'
```

Here's my code:

Url:`url(r'^addinterest/$', views.add_interest, name='add_interest'),`

View:

```
@login_required
def add_interest(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        #create a form instance and populate it with data from the request
        form = InterestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #process data in form.clean_data
            interest = form.cleaned_data['interest']
            user.add_interest(interest)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('add_interests.html', context)
    else:
        form=InterestForm()

    return render_to_response('add_interests.html', context, {'form': form})
```

Form:

```
class InterestForm(forms.Form):
    interest = forms.CharField(label="Enter a new Interest:", max_length=100)`
```

Template:

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Add Interests</h1>
</div> <!-- /container -->
<div class="container">
  This is your list:
  <ul>{% for i in user.profile.interests %}
  <li>{{i}} <button type="button">Remove Interest</button>
  {% endfor %}</ul>
</div> <!-- /container -->
<div class ="container">
  <form action="{% url add_interest %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Add Interest" />
  </form>
</div>
```

I'm new to Django, so I'm assuming this is a very simple fix but I couldn't find any other questions with 'dict' object has no attribute 'push'.

My interest field is part of a user profile model. The interest field is a ListView which I've seen used a lot of times on here.

```
class ListField(models.TextField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase
    description = "Stores a python list"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if not value:
            value = []

        if isinstance(value, list):
            return value

        return ast.literal_eval(value)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return value

        return unicode(value)

    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        value = self._get_val_from_obj(obj)
        return self.get_db_prep_value(value)
```

In my UserProfile model, here are the add and remove interest. I doubt this is the reason of the issue, but just in case, here are the functions.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):


    interests = ListField(blank=True)


    def add_interest(self, value):
        self.interests.insert(len(self.interests)+1, value)
        #self.save()
    def remove_interest(self, value):
        self.interests.remove(value)
        #self.save()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got your `render_to_response()` arguments mixed up:

```
return render_to_response('add_interests.html', context, {'form': form})
```

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) tells you the second argument is a dictionary, the 3rd the context instance, but you swapped them.

Best use the `context_instance` argument as a keyword argument:

```
return render_to_response('add_interests.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=context)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more case here. Even if the arguments were right and still you were getting the error, the following worked for me.

1. Change the `render_to_response` as render
2. wrap the `..../something.html` and `context_dict` inside braces.

ex:

```
context_dict = {}
context_dict.update(csrf(request))
return render(request,("xxxx/Test.html", context_dict), {})
```