# 'dict' object has no attribute 'push'

Tags: django, django-templates

My views.py:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #code
    else:
        form = #my_form
        context_dict = {}
        context_dict['myfield'] = 3
        return render(request, 'core/my_template.html', context_dict, {'form': form})
        #return render(request, 'core/my_template.html', {'form': form}, context_dict)
        #return render_to_response('core/my_template.html', context_dict, {'form': form})
        #return render_to_response('core/my_template.html', {'form': form}, context_dict)
```

It gives an AttributeError: `'dict' object has no attribute 'push'`

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567921/django-1-8-attributeerror-dict-object-has-no-attribute-push) but neither solutions work for me.

This line below doesn't gives error but looks like don't pass anything( `{{ myfield }}` doesn't print anything)

```
        return render(request, ('core/add_regent.html', context_dict), {'form': form})
```

I'm using django 1.9

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create one context dictionary including all context variables and pass it as the third argument:

```
context_dict = {}
context_dict['myfield'] = 3
context_dict['form'] = form
return render(request, 'core/my_template.html', context_dict)
```